# passing type with parameter in function call

Tags: go

The code below is from Jan Newmarch's  [book](http://jan.newmarch.name/go/socket/chapter-socket.html) about network programming in Go. In most of the Go code that I've seen (which is very little, as I'm a newbie, you don't (in a function call) pass a type with a parameter. However, in the code below, you see this line

```
conn.Write([]byte(daytime))
```

Why is it necessary to include `[]byte` in this function call?

```
func main() {

    service := ":1200"
    tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("ip4", service)
    checkError(err)

    listener, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", tcpAddr)
    checkError(err)

    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            continue
        }

        daytime := time.Now().String()
        conn.Write([]byte(daytime))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Conn.Write()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#IPConn.Write) expects the value as a byte slice. Since `daytime` is of type string you have to convert it.

You could rewrite the above as:

```
daytime := []byte(time.Now().String())
conn.Write(daytime)
```

Or, as @fabrizioM writes, you could use the formatted writer which would convert it:

```
fmt.Fprintf(conn, daytime)
```

Comment: More importantly, the Go spec contains a special case that allow you to convert a string into a byte slice.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is to use

```
fmt.Fprintf(conn, daytime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the data being transferred between server and client is byte.

The daytime in your case is obviously string format.

So you have to convert it into byte by using []byte(daytime).

Either way, you could import "bufio" to create a NewWriter for each client, and the NewWriter

will have the methods WriteString(""). At this moment, you could directly pass your daytime

as a parameter~